# Android 9 issues with Pixel

Tags: google-pixel, 9.0-pie

My Pixel phone is upgraded to Android 9.  I am having two different issues.

1. Voice to Text is not working
2. Callers cannot hear me on voice calls (callers can hear me on Bluetooth devices)

Anyone else experience this or know how to resolve?

Comment: OTA or clean install? Any issues prior to upgrade? Bad microphone (do other things like Assistant work?)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems surely the problem of hardware i.e. microphone. I have Pixel XL, and there are no software compatibility issues that i found yet. Still if u are very much sure, then you can factory reset the phone(it clears all the phone data and fresh start the Android) by going to **Settings -> System -> Reset Options -> Erase All Data**.

Note: It is recommended by many tech experts to Factory Reset the phone after installing an Android Version update as it clear unused previous OS caches.